# An upper bound on van der Waerden Numbers W(r, k), determined from the Number of Colorings r

Tags: combinatorics, ramsey-theory

Let $W(r, k)$ be a van der Waerden number, such that the interval $[1, W(r, k)]$ contains an arithmetic progression (AP) of $k$ terms, (k > 1), where the integers in the AP all have the same (monochromatic) coloring.

Let $n$ be the positive integer exponent for which $r^{n}$ divides $W(r, k)$ while $r^{n + 1}$ does not divide $W(r, k)$.

Let 
$$
b_{n}, b_{n - 1}, \ldots, b_{0} \in [0, r - 1],
$$ 
all be integers, with 
$$
1 \leq b_{n} < r,
$$ 
such that
\begin{equation}
W(r, k) = b_{n}r^{n} + b_{n - 1}r^{n - 1} + \ldots + b_{0}.
\end{equation}
QUESTION: Does anyone here claim that the following inequalities below are false when the arithmetic is done in base ten?
\begin{equation}
r^{n} \leq b_{n}r^{n} + b_{n - 1}r^{n - 1} + \ldots + b_{0} < r^{n + 1}.
\end{equation}
That is to say, since 
$$
W(r, k) = b_{n}r^{n} + b_{n - 1}r^{n - 1} + \ldots + b_{0},
$$
we have that
\begin{equation}
W(r, k) < r^{n + 1}.
\end{equation}
If anyone here claims these conclusions are false, then I am very much interested in seeing some helpful and valid counterarguments.

Here are three particular examples of what I mean when the number of colorings are respectively, (r = 3, r = 4, r = 2), and where (W(3, 3) = 27, W(4, 3) = 76, W(2, 6) = 1132).
\begin{eqnarray}
3^{3}&\leq&W(3, 3) = 3^{3} < 3^{4},\nonumber\\
4^{3}&\leq&W(4, 3) = 4^{3} + 3(4^{1}) < 4^{4},\nonumber\\
2^{10}&\leq&W(2, 6) = 2^{10} + 2^{6} + 2^{4} + 2^{2} < 2^{11}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: There's something odd going on here.  You say that $r^n$ divides $W(r,k)$, but then write $W(r,k)$ as $b_nr^n+b_{n-1}r^{n-1}+\dots+b_0$ where the $b_i$ are all integers contained in $[0,r-1]$.  But that then means that $b_1,\dots,b_{n-1}$ are all zero (since $r^n$ divides $W(r, k)$).  Moreover, if $W(r,k)$ can indeed be written in this form, it automatically implies that $W(r,k)<r^{n+1}$; however, there is no reason to suppose this to be true in general.

Comment: I should also point out that even if this were somehow true, it wouldn't (immediately) give an upper bound on the van der Waerden numbers at all.  Let $N$ be an arbitrarily huge number, and consider $W=r^N$.  If $W$ a van der Waerden number $W(r, k)$ (and if we make $N$ large enough, then it will be), then your $n$ would be equal to $N$, so we certainly have $W<r^{n+1}$.  But $W$ can now be made arbitrarily large by increasing $N$.